# Benchmarking compile-time properties of a program

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, constexpr

What is the best way to evaluate exact minimal value of `-fconstexpr-steps=` and `-ftemplate-depth=` parametres required for compilation of a program?

What I do currently is a bisection of a value. But for real-world template-loaded programs it became very long operation, even being logarithmic on upper limit of a value.

There is `-v` option and `-ftime-report`, but even their output not gives any desired information about maximum template depth actually used and number of steps actually passed during evaluation of constant expressions.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at how [**Boost.Hana**](https://github.com/boostorg/hana) does its benchmarking. Its benchmark code is written mostly in the form of [eRuby templates](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/tree/master/benchmark). The templates are used to generate C++ files which are then compiled while gathering compilation and execution statistics.

Bisection to find the necessary values of `-ftemplate-depth` and `-fconstexpr-steps` is of course a bit cumbersome to do by hand, but you could also write a script (Ruby, Python, whatever floats your boat) to automate this. Just double the initial value in a simple `while` loop until the program compiles successfully.